# print visual studio solution structure

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just want to document (via PDF) the solution directory structure of my VS solution. I can't seem to find a way in Visual Studio (2012) to print it. I tried printing the directory structure using the command prompt, but the VS solution directory tree that displays in the solution explorer is a virtual directory structure that is not necessarily implemented on the physical drive. I also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6955087/3178409), but this only parses the project files and not the solution. Has anyone figured out a way to print the solution directory tree without resorting to a screen shot?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955087/outputting-list-of-files-that-are-part-of-a-visual-studio-project) contains something that may help you, it is for visual studio 2008 but it shouldn't be too different.

Comment: @ichrammm That answer won't work because Visual Studio 2012, doesn't support macros.

Answer (score 2):

From a command prompt:

DIR c:\whatever\directory /s

or

DIR c:\whatever\directory /s /b

or

TREE c:\whatever\directory

You can redirect the output to a text file and print that to PDF or open in Word and save as PDF or ...